# Every day at the same time Google removes all my history in Chrome browser on all devices

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-search

Every day at the same time, Google clears all my history in Chrome browser (iPads, Android phones, desktop PC, notebook, connected in one Google account), as well as quick access URLs in the address bar, and sites on the Quick Launch page. 
What is happening and how I can stop this madness?

Comment: Do you run any privacy applications (like CCleaner) on any of your devices?

Comment: @Steven No, nothing is installed and have not changed anything in  the account settings.

Answer (score 2):

Google does not provide an option to clear browser history on a schedule.

First, check for any unknown devices accessing your Google account: https://myaccount.google.com/security

If that does not fix the issue, you'll have to determine which device is deleting your history.  Since you know the exact time, this should be straightforward.

1. Each day before that time, power off one device.
2. Check your history on a second device.
3. If the history remains, you have the affected device.
4. If the history is cleared, repeat for a different device.

Once you locate the affected device, check for any privacy applications or malware.

Comment: @Astraport Did you solve this issue?